# read in text and convert to integer array

Tags: tensorflow

I have a csv file, where each line is in the form

```
"0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,20,0,17,0,0"
```

I have tried to read the data in with this function

```
    def decode_csv(line):
        line_split = tf.string_split([line], ',')
        features= tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[:-1], tf.int32)
        label= tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[-1], tf.int32)
        return features, label

    dataset =tf.data.TextLineDataset("Documents/t1.csv").skip(1).map(decode_csv3)
    dataset=dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=2).repeat(-1).batch(2)
    dataset_init=dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    x,y= dataset_init.get_next()
```

I want to convert each line to the form

```
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,20,0,17,0]
```

for x

and

```
[0]
```

for y

I am receiving the error

```
 invalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: "0
 [[Node: StringToNumber = StringToNumber[out_type=DT_FLOAT](strided_slice)]]
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext_25 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator_25)]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the idea form @agillgilla, I got this to work

```
def decode_csv(line):
    line = tf.py_func(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8").strip('"'), [line], tf.string)
    line_split = tf.string_split([line], ',')
    features= tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[:-1], tf.int32)
    label= tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[-1], tf.int32)
    return features, label

dataset =tf.data.TextLineDataset("Documents/t1.csv").skip(1).map(decode_csv3)
dataset=dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=2).repeat(-1).batch(2)
dataset_init=dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
x,y= dataset_init.get_next()
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to strip the double quotes from the string.

Try this:

```
def decode_csv(line):
    line = line.strip('\"')
    line_split = tf.string_split([line], ',')
    features= tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[:-1], tf.int32)
    label= tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[-1], tf.int32)
    return features, label

dataset =tf.data.TextLineDataset("Documents/t1.csv").skip(1).map(decode_csv3)
dataset=dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=2).repeat(-1).batch(2)
dataset_init=dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
x,y= dataset_init.get_next()
```